How to create global row numbers in a distributed way in pySpark
I am trying to create row numbers for my data that is distributed across multiple partitions and possibly on different nodes of a cluster.
Below is the code that I used to divide the data into multiple partitions based on the Data column
from pyspark.sql import Window, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number, sum, spark_partition_id, monotonically_increasing_id, min, max
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

empDF = spark.read.csv("dbfs:/FileStore/large_data.csv", header=True)

empDFPartId = empDF.repartitionByRange(4,col("Data")).withColumn("partition_id", spark_partition_id()).cache()

partitionsDF = empDFPartId \
  .select("partition_id") \
  .groupBy("partition_id") \
  .count() \
  .withColumn(
    "count",
    sum("count").over(Window.orderBy("partition_id")) - col("count").cast("int")
  )

#partitionsDF.show()

empDFRowNumber = empDFPartId \
  .join(
    partitionsDF,
    ["partition_id"]
  ) \
  .withColumn(
    "row_number_within_partition",
    row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("partition_id").orderBy("Data"))
  ) \
  .withColumn(
    "row_number",
    col("count") + col("row_number_within_partition")
  )

empDFRowNumber \
  .write \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .csv("dbfs:/FileStore/partition_1")

This code gave me a global row number but there were gaps in the sequence. Below is the output of the min and max row number present in each partition



partition_id
min
max
count




0
1
999999
4291703


1
4291704
8584071
4292368


2
10000000
9999999
4292208


3
12876280
17169548
4293269



Does anyone know if there is any other way ?

although I've given a general answer it'd be good if you could specify what properties your id's should have.

I am looking to create a sequence that starts from 1.

monotonically_increasing_id effectively does exactly what you have coded (albeit far faster).  You cannot get fully sequential numbers or even well distributed "ids", partitions may have different row counts in them.
Moreover if you run the same query again you'll probably get the same ids generated on different rows.  If you want truly unique id per generation (also across clusters) you'll need something like Quality's guaranteed unique id's (basically monotonically_increasing_id and snowflake ids combined).
